# Converting multi index data frame to nested dictionaries - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested, multi-index

in Python I have the following multi index data frame:

|  |  |  | *level 3* | col 1 | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *level 1* | *level 2* | *level 3* | *level 4* | **col 1a** | **col 1b** | **col 2** | **col 3** |
| **A** | **Aa** | **Aaa** | **type1** | val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4 |
| **A** | **Aa** | **Aaa** | **type2** | val 5 | val 6 | val 7 | val 8 |
| **A** | **Ab** | **Aab** | **type1** | val 9 | val 10 | ... | ... |
| **A** | **Ac** | **Aac** | **type2** | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| **B** | **Ba** | **Baa** | **type1** | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| **B** | **Ba** | **Bab** | **type3** | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| **C** | **Ca** | **Caa** | **type4** | ... | ... | ... | ... |

To explain the data frame:

- First 2 rows are multi index headers
- First 4 columns are multi index headers
- level 1, 2, 3, 4 and empty spaces are index area

From this list, my aim is to get a dictionary such as:

- First option is A , B or C
- If clicked on A, next choice is Aa , Ab or Ac
- If clicked on Aa, next choice is only Aaa (if only Aaa is available)
- If clicked on Aaa, next choice is type 1 or type 2
- If clicked on type1, next choice is col 1 or col 2 or col3
- If clicked on col1, next choice is col 1a or col 1b
- If clicked on col 1a, we find the val 1 as final output

Please, give me directions on how to do this transformation. Also, new viewpoints and suggestions about how to approach this case is very appreciated as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following dataframe `df`:

```
                 col 1           col 2   col 3
                col 1a  col 1b   col 2   col 3
A Aa Aaa type1   val 1   val 2   val 3   val 4
         type2   val 5   val 6   val 7   val 8
  Ab Aab type1   val 9  val 10  val 11  val 12
  Ac Aac type2  val 13  val 14  val 15  val 16
B Ba Baa type1  val 17  val 18  val 19  val 20
     Bab type3  val 21  val 22  val 23  val 24
C Ca Caa type4  val 25  val 26  val 27  val 28
```

**Step 1**: Further flattening:

```
df_sub = (
    df.loc[:, [("col 1", "col 1a"), ("col 1", "col 1b")]]
      .melt(ignore_index=False)
      .set_index(["variable_0", "variable_1"], append=True)
)
```

Result:

```
                                       value
               variable_0 variable_1        
A Aa Aaa type1 col 1      col 1a       val 1
         type2 col 1      col 1a       val 5
  Ab Aab type1 col 1      col 1a       val 9
  Ac Aac type2 col 1      col 1a      val 13
B Ba Baa type1 col 1      col 1a      val 17
     Bab type3 col 1      col 1a      val 21
C Ca Caa type4 col 1      col 1a      val 25
A Aa Aaa type1 col 1      col 1b       val 2
         type2 col 1      col 1b       val 6
  Ab Aab type1 col 1      col 1b      val 10
  Ac Aac type2 col 1      col 1b      val 14
B Ba Baa type1 col 1      col 1b      val 18
     Bab type3 col 1      col 1b      val 22
C Ca Caa type4 col 1      col 1b      val 26
```

**Step 2**: Nesting (recursive):

```
def nest(df):
    if df.index.nlevels == 1:
        return df.to_dict()[df.columns[0]]
    return {
        key: nest(df_grp.droplevel(0, axis=0))
        for key, df_grp in df.groupby(level=0)
    }

result = nest(df_sub)
```

Result:

```
{'A': {'Aa': {'Aaa': {'type1': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 1',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 2'}},
                      'type2': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 5',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 6'}}}},
       'Ab': {'Aab': {'type1': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 9',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 10'}}}},
       'Ac': {'Aac': {'type2': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 13',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 14'}}}}},
 'B': {'Ba': {'Baa': {'type1': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 17',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 18'}}},
              'Bab': {'type3': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 21',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 22'}}}}},
 'C': {'Ca': {'Caa': {'type4': {'col 1': {'col 1a': 'val 25',
                                          'col 1b': 'val 26'}}}}}}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

The 2. step could be done differently:

```
result = {}
for keys, value in df_sub.itertuples():
    last = result
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        last = last.setdefault(key, {})
    last[keys[-1]] = value
```